# Selenium Webdriver get() shows intermittent TimeoutExceptions - how do I proceed?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, python

I'm using Selenium Webdriver for testing a Django/Python based web application. I use both, the phantomjs and firefox drivers. We use django's LiveServerTest test case, which basically starts up a test webserver for the app.

Now, on our CI environment (wercker), I sometimes - but not always - get a TimeoutException from my webdriver.get(url) calls. The thing is, though, that when I look at the screenshots (which I collect on exceptions) the actual page seems to be rendered just fine.

I'm already using a technique to wait for a page reload that is described here: http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html. This wrapper basically waits until the old page's HTML element is replaced with the new one. It seemed to resolve similar problems for when I run my tests locally.

So, what am I experiencing here? How can I proceed? Any hints greatly apreciated.

Edit: I followed Artem's advice and remove all external resources (fonts and google maps calls). I initially thought that helped but then got other errors instead. I now get TimeoutExceptions in a click() call... Here's the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pipeline/build/flatfox/tests/ui/utils.py", line 57, in wrapper
    func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/pipeline/build/flatfox/tests/ui/test_auction_cycle.py", line 157, in test_manage_applications
    self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.modal-dialog .btn[name=reject]').click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 65, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 385, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message: u'{"errorMessage":"Click failed: timeout","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"81","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:55196","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\\"sessionId\\": \\"d67c58a0-610d-11e4-a75e-eb735e81fd4c\\", \\"id\\": \\":wdc:1414767284194\\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/d67c58a0-610d-11e4-a75e-eb735e81fd4c/element/%3Awdc%3A1414767284194/click"}}' ; Screenshot: available via screen
```

Edit: Here's the code making the click():

```
with wait_for_page_load(self.driver):
    self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.modal-dialog .btn[name=reject]').click()
```

with

```
def wait_for(condition_function):
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() < start_time + 10:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        if condition_function():
            return True
    raise Exception('Timeout waiting for {0}'.format(condition_function.__name__))

class wait_for_page_load(object):
    def __init__(self, browser):
        self.browser = browser

    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_page = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html')

    def page_has_loaded(self):
        new_page = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
        return new_page.id != self.old_page.id

    def __exit__(self, *_):
        try:
            wait_for(self.page_has_loaded)
        except Exception, e:
            logging.getLogger("test.ui").error("wait_for_page_load(): failed with %s", e)
```

I'm a bit lost now and wonder whether it has something to do with the CI environment...

Thanks,
Bernhard

Comment: What locators are you using for waiting? I assume you use only explicit waits and expected_contition, am I right? +1 for good researched question. Show us the code.

Answer (score 3):

In selenium the wait command doesn't really wait sometimes. That is there is some problem with that command.

You can try the time.sleep(); command of python. It is an equivalent of the Thread.sleep(); command of Java.

It will pause the execution of code for defined time limit. So you can give sufficient time that will allow your page to load.

Hope it works... :)

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention it, but I've already surrounded the calls by `time.sleep(1)`s. This did indeed help on my local environment, but doesn't solve the problem on wercker.

Comment: Did you try it with more time? Maybe 5 seconds instead of 1 or maybe 10. It may be that the time u defined is not sufficient.

Comment: I have my wait settings at 8 for both, page reload and implicit wait... I'm now trying to up those numbers...
Thanks

Comment: Okay. Try that and do let me know if it works. A lot of people are having trouble with the wait command of selenium and in java usually the Thread.sleep() seems to resolve it. So i'd like to know if the python equivalent does the trick as well!

Comment: Hmm, okay. I didn't surround the click command with sleeps, so I'm going to try that one as well...

Answer (score 3):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) 
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'someid')))
```

Try above code and see if it is working or not.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. The thing is, I don't really get out of the `get()` call at all, since it already triggers the Exception.

Answer (score 3):

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds 
driver.get("http:// enter your URL.") 
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")
```

Try above code and see if it is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

The possible reason might be that page looks to be rendered (UI elements are in place), but not completely loaded in browser.

If there is any background calls, especially to 3rd-party services, it might take a while to reach them and get response, only then browser is able to mark the page as finally loaded.

Comment: Ah, nice, I'm going to look into that. I do have a few external resources on my page (fonts, maps). I try to disable those and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

thank you all for your suggestions. Though it's still not perfect, I now have a better working environment. I combined Artem's suggestion of removing external dependencies with Pushpendra's tip to boost up implicit_wait and page_load_timeout further up. They are now at 12 and 30, but I intend to go even higher. I've also increased the sleep times, as suggested by milinpatel17, to as high as 4 seconds around calls that don't reload the page, but modify the DOM in a way.

The core of the problem seems to be that the CI environment's cpu loading sometimes is  unpredictable and I have to make enough room for those times it is laggy. This is also what wercker's support suggested (nice guys, btw). I will now make these timeout values dependant on the environment, such that I can run local tests fast and then slow down on the CI.

I can't mark a single answer as valid, and, unfortunately, my reputation doesn't allow upvoting... sorry. But many thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ultimate solution specifically when you are dealing with Angular 7 or 8.

Instead of waiting for a longer duration using sleep or implicit wait methods, you can divide your wait time into the partition and use it recursively.

Below logic will wait for the page to render for a minimum of 300 seconds and a maximum of 900 seconds.

```
/**
 * This method will check page loading
 *
 */
public void waitForLoadingToComplete() {
    waitLoadingTime(3); // Enter the number of attempts you want to try
}

 private void waitLoadingTime(int i) {
        try {
  // wait for the loader to appear after particular action/click/navigation
            this.staticWait(300); 
  // check for the loader and wait till loader gets disappear
            waitForElementToBeNotPresent(By.cssSelector("Loader Element CSS"));                                                             
        } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e) {
            if (i != 0)
                waitLoadingTime(i - 1);
        }
    }

/**
 * This method is for the static wait
 *
 * @param millis
 */
public void staticWait(final long millis) {
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(millis);
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println("Error in staticWait." + e);
    }
}

public void waitForElementToBeNotPresent(final By element) {
    long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
    new WebDriverWait(this.getDriver(), 30)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(element)));
    System.err.println("Waiting for Element to be not present completed. " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - s));
}
```

Comment: So your plan is to just ignore them? I'm not sure that's the "ultimate solution"...